# how to pass array value to excel

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array(4) {
 [0]=>
 string(2) "12"
 [1]=>
 string(2) "17"
 [2]=>
 string(2) "1.0"
 [3]=>
 string(2) "1.7"
 }
 array(4) {
 [0]=>
 string(1) "3"
 [1]=>
 string(1) "1"
 [2]=>
 string(2) "4.1"
 [3]=>
 string(2) "4.6"
 }
```

I need to pass the value into excel(start from column C)
My code is

```
  foreach ($rate as $row) { 
        $i = 0;
        $j = 2;

        foreach ($row as $item) {

            $myxls->write_string($i, $j++, $row);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

But why I can only wrote the second array(3,1,4.1,4.6) in the first line. The first row is missing. Anything wrong in my foreach ?

Comment: your overwriting the first array with the 2nd

Answer (score 0):

Stating from column C

```
$this->load->library('phpExcel/PHPExcel');
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(11);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


$array = array(
array('name' => 'myname1', 'email' => 'email1'),
array('name' => 'myname2', 'email' => 'email2')
);

$num=0;

foreach($array as $v) {
 $num++;
 $objSheet->getCell('C'.$num)->setValue($v['name']);
 $objSheet->getCell('D'.$num)->setValue($v['email']);
}

$objWriter->save("file.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Excell first row index will be 1 not 0. Your are going to write first array to row 0 and second array to row 1, so first array could not write and second array is writing to first row.

Use,

```
$i = 1;
```

Instead of

```
$i = 0;
```